# Вывод информации из json в html

Tags: php, javascript, html, json, menu

есть задача выводить данные из json:

```
<?php
$json=file_get_contents("http://kap..ru/api/api.php?action=menu");
$data =  json_decode($json);

print_r($data);
?>
и там информация имеет структуру:

"id":"489",
"name":"53686172959bfc974eed379.32741418.jpg",
"title":"",
"description":"",
"weight":"",
"cost":"",
"sort":"351",
"img_preview":{
"path":"http:\/\/test.ru\/\/menu\/mini\/\/53686172959bfc974eed379.32741418.jpg",
"file_time":0
},
"img_big":{
"path":"http:\/\/test.ru\/\/menu\/maxi\/\/53686172959bfc974eed379.32741418.jpg",
"file_time":0
}
```

Как вывести структурированные данные в html страницу и использовать как меню  сайта ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/** Предполагаем что там массив данных
[ {"id":"1", "path":"http://kap..ru/image_1.png", "title":"Пункт 1"},
{"id":"2", "path":"http://kap..ru/image_2.png", "title":"Пункт 2"}]
*/
$json = file_get_contents("http://kap..ru/api/api.php?action=menu");
$data =  json_decode($json, true);

// В данном цикле выводим изображение в блок
$html = "<div class=\"block\">";
foreach($data as $value) {
    $id = $value['id'];
    $img = $value['path'];
    $title = $value['title'];
    $html .= "<a href=\"http://some.url.com/$id\" title=\"$title\"><img src=\"$img\" /></a>";
}
$html .= "</div>";
// Вывод на страницу с проверкой что массив дата не пустой
if(!empty($data)) echo $html;
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы вывести и использовать эти данные нужно передать в функцию `json_decode` второй параметр `true`, который укажет функции сформировать данные в ассоциативный массив.

В этом случае в переменной `data` у вас окажется ассоциативный массив перебирая который с помощью `foreach` выводите нужные данные в меню сайта.

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ я в этом новичок, а можно небольшой пример, вижу, что вы в этом разбираетесь пример подходящий под мою ситуацию.

Comment: @Cruze Fan чтобы дать под вашу ситуацию нужно знать что и в какую часть меню выводить. Дайте код меню и какой элемент из массива нужно в него писать.